# How to set menu location at the bottom of buttons bottom in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the location of a menu that opens from a button's click.
I need that the bottom of the menu will be at the same horizontal line as the bottom of the button.

My code example with the error in this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/gfu07znv/)

I'm trying to do the same as this [`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FWW/1819/). This works with one button but not with 2 buttons.

Comment: `bottom:0` -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gfu07znv/1/

Comment: thanx, but now both menus opens from the bottom of the lower button. I need each menu to be relative to it's own button.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this jsfiddle for example of work and choose as accepted answer, if that what you need.

[twoBoxMenu Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ShadowMad/zt8gf58z/1/)

What I did is that I canceled out commeted `position:absolute` in class uiBarButton and then added wrapper class for each of the box. And gave that wrapper following code:

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

What it does is that when you have something in position absolute you can control its initial placement with position relative of super element in DOM. That exactly what I did, as you can see wrapper class has position relative and doesnt allow run off of your boxes, it keeps them seperate. I added some margin for wrapper div so they would be seperated as you wished.

Also, in class uiMenu, I have changed bottom to value of 0, so any element will start from 0 with position absolute

```
.uiMenu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #18BECD;
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 bottom:0; }
```

Comment: Glad I helped, can you please accept this as answer